# Changing XAMPP MySQL port in Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, ports

After I have updated Google Chrome, mySql database status became deactivated. It has something to do with ports because now Chrome uses port 80 which has been used by Mysql before. How can I change either of them so my database runs properly? I would note that Apache Web Server also runs on port 80 but it's working correctly. I was looking for any answers but none of them were helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it by editing "my.cnf".

```
File Location: XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf
```

Then look for

```
port=80
```

and change it to a different port number, that is open.